# Undeclared identifier that was defined within a do-while loop

Tags: c, do-while, cs50, undeclared-identifier

Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(void)
{
    int answer_compared;

    do  {
        printf("What is your credit card number?\n");
        long long credit_card = GetLongLong ();
        printf("Is your credit card number is %lld?\n", credit_card);
        printf("Please respond Yes or No.\n");
        string answer = GetString ();
        answer_compared = strncasecmp(answer, "y", 1);
    } while (answer_compared != 0);
    int long long cc = credit_card;
    printf("Thank you.\n"); 
    if (cc == 4){
        printf("Visa\n");
    }else if (cc == 34 || cc == 37){
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }else if (cc >= 51 && cc <= 55){
        printf("MC\n");
    }else printf("You did not enter an appropriate credit card.\n");
        printf("I think this is what I need.\n");

}
```

My error is:

```
credit.c:17:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'credit_card'
        int long long cc = credit_card;
                           ^
```

Originally I had all of my cc variables set to credit_card but changed it because it added 5 more errors that was all for the same reason.  I attempted to find places that discussed creating variables within do-while loops, to no avail.

Can you explain what's going wrong here?

Comment: (a. k. a., read that tutorial **carefully.**)

Answer (score 1):

C has a block scope. You need to declare your variable (`long long credit_card`) in an outer scope (e.g. the function's scope like you did it with `answer_compared`) if you want to access it there.

Besides that, a credit card number is not a "number" when it comes to data types. You shouldn't store it as one - use a `char[20]` instead (16 digits, 3 separators, nul terminator)! You might want to normalize it though (remove separators between the 4 blocks) so you can access single digits properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define

```
long long credit_card
```

outside the do while loop

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, as the others have mentioned, this comes down to scope. You could move

```
printf("What is your credit card number?\n");
long long credit_card = GetLongLong ();
```

Before your do statement and that should clear the issue.  In general it's good practice to initialize variables at the beginning of a function and then set their values later on.